# How to declare a pandas dtype constant

Tags: pandas

I need to synthesize an array of pandas datatypes (due to situational handling of empty/null columns). How can I create a `pandas.dtype` constant for example on

```
pd.dtype('int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

Can it be a categorical `dtype`? If so then you can do it with `Pandas.CategoricalDtype`.  See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html.

Comment: I doubt that will work since the output we need should  be in basic primitive types